# How to bind a List of colors to property that requires Brush?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xaml, data-binding, winui-3

I've spent all day trying to figure out how I can simply have a list of colors (for example: Colors.AliceBlue) as my ItemsSource for a GridView and bind those colors to a Fill property of a Rectangle inside the DataTemplate. I know the Fill property must be a brush, so I have tried using a converter to convert the color to a SolidColorBrush, but it has not worked. I've also tried not using a converter and instead changing the List to List but that did not work either. No matter what I do, I keep getting binding errors that say:

> Converter failed to convert value of type '#FFF0F8FF' to type 'Brush'. Binding: Path='' DataItem='#FFF0F8FF'; target element is 'Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Shapes.Rectangle' (Name='null'); target property is 'Fill' (type 'Brush')

Everything I try always seems to return my color as an ARGB, in this case "#FFF0F8FF", which is not what the property accepts. Any ideas on how to bind my list of colors to my item/data  template? I definitely want to use color names in my list, as it is easier to access colors this way rather than looking up their RGB codes and whatnot.

---

**Page.xaml**

```
<GridView ItemsSource="{x:Bind ColorOptions}" IsItemClickEnabled="True" SelectionMode="Single">
    <GridView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Rectangle Fill="{Binding}" Width="40" Height="40" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </GridView.ItemTemplate>
</GridView>
```

**Page.xaml.cs**

```
using System.Windows.Media;
...
public readonly List<Color> ColorOptions = new()
{
    Colors.AliceBlue,
    Colors.Black,
    Colors.DarkBlue,
    Colors.Brown,
    Colors.DarkGreen,
    Colors.Magenta
};
```

---

Also, if you're interested, here's the converter I created and tried, but also did not work.

**BrushConverter.cs**

```
using System.Windows.Media;
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Data;

namespace App.Helpers;

public class BrushConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object? Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        return new SolidColorBrush((Color)value);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        return ((SolidColorBrush)value).Color;
    }
}
```

**Page.xaml (using converter)**

```
<GridView ItemsSource="{x:Bind ColorOptions}" IsItemClickEnabled="True" SelectionMode="Single">
    <GridView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Rectangle Fill="{Binding Converter={StaticResource BrushConverter}}" Width="40" Height="40" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </GridView.ItemTemplate>
</GridView>
```

Comment: Is this WinUI3? I am testing your code but can't seem to use System.Windows.Media. Also, you should use a ViewModel then bind to your Page, as the ColorOptions acts like a variable in your code

Comment: Yes, I am using WinUI3. Also, thanks for the tip about the ViewModel. I've fairly new to this and was always confused as to what the view models were for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This way you don't need a converter:

```cs
using Microsoft.UI;
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Media;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Windows.UI;

namespace GridViews;

public class ColorOption
{
    public ColorOption(string name, Color color)
    {
        Name = name;
        Color = new SolidColorBrush(color);
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Brush Color { get; set; }
}

public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    public List<ColorOption> ColorOptions { get; } = new()
    {
        new ColorOption("Alice Blue", Colors.AliceBlue),
        new ColorOption("Black", Colors.Black),
        new ColorOption("Dark Blue", Colors.DarkBlue),
        new ColorOption("Brown", Colors.Brown),
        new ColorOption("Dark Green", Colors.DarkGreen),
        new ColorOption("Magenta", Colors.Magenta),
    };
}
```

```xml
<GridView
    IsItemClickEnabled="True"
    ItemsSource="{x:Bind ColorOptions}"
    SelectionMode="Single">
    <GridView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:ColorOption">
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Name}" />
                <Rectangle
                    Width="40"
                    Height="40"
                    Fill="{x:Bind Color}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </GridView.ItemTemplate>
</GridView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Had to change some things as I can't use System.Windows.Media:

1. On Page/Window.xaml

```xml
<Window
    ...
    xmlns:helpers="using:TestApp.Helpers"   
    xmlns:vm="using:TestApp.ViewModels"
    ...>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.Resources>
            <vm:MainViewModel x:Name="ViewModel" />
            <helpers:BrushConverter x:Name="BrushConverter" />
        </Grid.Resources>
        <GridView ItemsSource="{x:Bind ViewModel.ColorOptions, Mode=OneWay}">
            <GridView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Rectangle Width="40" Height="40" Fill="{Binding Converter={StaticResource BrushConverter}}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </GridView.ItemTemplate>
        </GridView>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

2. Use a ViewModel (e.g. MainViewModel.cs)

```cs
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;

namespace TestApp.ViewModels;

public class MainViewModel
{
    public List<Color> ColorOptions { get; } = new()
    {
       Color.Red,
       Color.Orange,
       Color.Yellow
    };
}
```

3. BrushConverter.cs (Drawing.Color to Windows.UI.Color) for my end

```cs
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
{
    var drawingColor = (System.Drawing.Color)value;
    return new SolidColorBrush(Windows.UI.Color.FromArgb(drawingColor.A, drawingColor.R, drawingColor.G, drawingColor.B));
}
```

**Output**
[image: App]

Comment: Unfortunately this still brought up a binding error: Converter failed to convert value of type '#FFFF0000' to type 'Brush'. Binding: Path='' DataItem='System.Windows.Media.Color'; target element is 'Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Shapes.Rectangle' (Name='null'); target property is 'Fill' (type 'Brush')